# Custom animation in splash screen in a Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, animation, splash-screen

I want to make a custom animated splash screen for a project in Flutter.

The output I want is like the one in this [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SemSpOOWRidSsyq8Io9mFRcm8lmNKiii/view?usp=sharing), but I am almost new to animating in Flutter and have no idea how to progress on this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the official documentation about [animations](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/animations) at first. Also to achieve your desired output, I think [lottie](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie) provides a good solution which you try out.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn you video `.mp4` to `.gif` or `.json` Use online converters such as [Lottie](https://lottiefiles.com/) or many others. Then Do this;

```
Image.asset(
          "assets/your_animation.gif",
          height: 200,
        ),
```

2. In the case of lottie files, use this package [lottie](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie) and import this package

```
..
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
..
Lottie.asset(
          "assets/your_animation.json",
          height: 200,
        ),
```

Comment: Actually, it is a Figma presentation and not exactly a video.